# Accessing Data on a Closed Excel Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I use the following to populate my current working spreadsheet with data from a collection of closed spreadsheets.

```
Workbooks(Range("E24").Value).Worksheets("Labor_R").Range("N5:P10").Value = _
    Workbooks(Range("A22").Value).Worksheets("Page1_1").Range("A5:C10").Value
```

The cell content of `E24` and `A22` are the document names (not the full path).  My working document remains the same, but I loop through a list of other documents from `A22`.  Those document names are text strings built/stored in `A22`.  The document names are correct.

This all works fine when all of the documents are in the same directory (full path not required).  I do not open each spreadsheet.  I do not use Copy/Paste. As soon I attempt to build the full path in `A22`, I get "Subscript out of range".

I have tried to do this by adding brackets around the document name and the single quotation marks around the entire path/doc_name.  Always the same error.

Hopefully this is something simple that I have overlooked, but I have been trying to work through this for a couple of days now without success.

Comment: Post your code attempts

Comment: There are only two way (I know of) to access data out of a closed Excel workbook. 1) ADO 2) ExecuteExcel4Macro. The way you have shown above `Workbooks(Range("E24").Value).Worksheets("Labor_R").Range("N5:P10").Value = _ Workbooks(Range("A22").Value).Worksheets("Page1_1").Range("A5:C10").Value` will not work on a closed workbook.

Comment: @Kyle is correct that `Worksbooks(...).Worksheets(...).Range(...)` only works on open files. An Excel formula can reach into a closed file, e.g.: `='C:\Path\[Workbook_Name.xlsx]Worksheet_Name'!$A$1`.  In VBA you could reach into a closed file by writing such a formula to the `.Formula` of a cell in an open workbook, then read the `.Value` of that cell.

Comment: Open the file in the background, it is always easier (and much quicker for large data grabs) than fiddling with ADO, XLM or creating direct links